# Как смягчить действие фильтра SVG? Получить более сглаженные границы?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-filter

Есть работа фильтров SVG и последующая анимация через JS. Настраиваю `feTurbulence`, передаю на вход `feDisplacementMap`, но получаю довольно "жесткий" результат - границы эффекта угловатые, не сглаженные.

```js
const SCALE_MAX = 1;
const SCALE_MIN = 0.2;
const SCALE_STEP = 0.004;

let disp_map = document.querySelector('feDisplacementMap');
let turbulence = document.querySelector('feTurbulence');

let scale = SCALE_MIN + SCALE_STEP;
let dir = 1;

draw();

function draw(){
    disp_map.setAttribute('scale', scale*10);
    turbulence.setAttribute('baseFrequency', scale/10);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    
    if(scale >= SCALE_MAX || scale <= SCALE_MIN) dir = -dir;
        
    scale += SCALE_STEP * dir;       
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="disp-filter">
        <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.3" type="turbulence" numOctaves="2" result="turbulence"/>
        <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic" scale="0.5"/>
    </filter>   
    <text font-size="40px" textLength="80%" y="40" x ="100" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle"
            style="filter: url(#disp-filter); font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold">ВОДА</text>
</svg>
```

Для сглаживания пробую добавить `feGaussianBlur` после `feTurbulence` и получаю совершенно неожиданный результат:

```js
const SCALE_MAX = 1;
const SCALE_MIN = 0.2;
const SCALE_STEP = 0.004;

let disp_map = document.querySelector('feDisplacementMap');
let turbulence = document.querySelector('feTurbulence');

let scale = SCALE_MIN + SCALE_STEP;
let dir = 1;

draw();

function draw(){
    disp_map.setAttribute('scale', scale*10);
    turbulence.setAttribute('baseFrequency', scale/10);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    
    if(scale >= SCALE_MAX || scale <= SCALE_MIN) dir = -dir;
        
    scale += SCALE_STEP * dir;       
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="disp-filter">
      <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.3" type="turbulence" numOctaves="2" result="turbulence"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" />
      <feDisplacementMap in2="blur" in="SourceGraphic" scale="0.5"/>
  </filter>   
  <text font-size="40px" textLength="80%" y="40" x ="100" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle"
         style="filter: url(#disp-filter); font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold">ВОДА</text>
</svg>
```

Если выставляю `blur` дополнительным фильтром в `style` элемента `text`, или пробую размытие `feDisplacementMap`, то любой эффект кроме `blur` пропадает.

**Как можно доработать фильтр (`<filter id="disp-filter">`), чтобы получить более сглаженные границы?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему бы не использовать комбинацию из CSS и SVG фильтров? Свойство `filter` допускает цепочки. Кстати, если размытие в 1px слишком велико, то в фильтре `blur()` возможно указывать дробное значение пикселей.

```js
const SCALE_MAX = 1;
const SCALE_MIN = 0.2;
const SCALE_STEP = 0.004;

let disp_map = document.querySelector('feDisplacementMap');
let turbulence = document.querySelector('feTurbulence');

let scale = SCALE_MIN + SCALE_STEP;
let dir = 1;

draw();

function draw(){
    disp_map.setAttribute('scale', scale*10);
    turbulence.setAttribute('baseFrequency', scale/10);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    
    if(scale >= SCALE_MAX || scale <= SCALE_MIN) dir = -dir;
        
    scale += SCALE_STEP * dir;       
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="disp-filter">
        <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.3" type="turbulence" numOctaves="2" result="turbulence"/>
        <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic" scale="0.5"/>
    </filter>   
    <text font-size="40px" textLength="80%" y="40" x ="100" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle"
            style="filter: url(#disp-filter) blur(.6px); font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold">ВОДА</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Именно так я и пробовал, только я добавил запятую после первого фильтра((( и ничего не работало. Спасибо, именно это и нужно было!

Comment: @Leonid: там разделитель - это пробел. И порядок важен.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно ответу [UModel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/265406/umodel) создал отдельно фильтр `feGaussianBlur` и добавил в стили цепочкой. Добавляю этот вариант потому, что он позволяет величину размытия указать в относительных единицах, а не привязываться к пикселям:

```js
const SCALE_MAX = 1;
const SCALE_MIN = 0.2;
const SCALE_STEP = 0.004;

let disp_map = document.querySelector('feDisplacementMap');
let turbulence = document.querySelector('feTurbulence');

let scale = SCALE_MIN + SCALE_STEP;
let dir = 1;

draw();

function draw(){
    disp_map.setAttribute('scale', scale*10);
    turbulence.setAttribute('baseFrequency', scale/10);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    
    if(scale >= SCALE_MAX || scale <= SCALE_MIN) dir = -dir;
        
    scale += SCALE_STEP * dir;       
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<filter id="disp-filter">
    <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.3" type="turbulence" numOctaves="2" result="turbulence"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic" scale="0.5"/>
</filter>
<filter id='blur-filter'>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.4"/>
</filter>
<text font-size="40px" textLength="80%" y="40" x ="100" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle"
        style="filter: url(#disp-filter) url(#blur-filter); font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold">ВОДА</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Хотя если открыть на всю страницу, то видно, что разницы никакой нет))

Comment: а Вы проказник ;-) Разве ж можно что-то заблюренное, да ещё и анимированное открывать на всю страницу? Если оперативка забита, то вылет браузера ооочень вероятен))